# JavaFX Display new label then sleep each iteration of a loop

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am creating a black jack program for my final project in my Java class and I want to simulate a dealer giving himself cards at the end of a round. I want to sleep each iteration of a while loop for 1 second to show a slight pause. The following are 2 attempts that I have taken based on different threads I've read on stack overflow but neither works.

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), event ->
        {
            if(dealer.getScore() < 17 || (dealer.getScore() < player.getScore() && dealer.getScore() <= 21))
            {
                newCard(dealer, mainDeck.deal(), false);
                System.out.println("Running Here!");
                LBLDeck.setText(String.valueOf(mainDeck.getRemaingCards()) + " cards remaining");
            }
        })
);
timeline.setCycleCount(1);
System.out.println("Starting loop!");
```

and this one:

```
while (dealer.getScore() < 17 || (dealer.getScore() < player.getScore() && dealer.getScore() <= 21))
{
    new Thread(() ->
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            newCard(dealer, mainDeck.deal(), false);
            LBLDeck.setText(String.valueOf(mainDeck.getRemaingCards()) + " cards remaining");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).run();
}
```

I am not too sure what is wrong with the first example because I have never worked with timelines before. As for the second, it seems to count the total amount of slept time and freeze my program for that duration. I.E. if the loop went 3 times my program sleeps for 3 seconds then continues. Then it spits all of the labels out at once.

Comment: Has been said multiple times, and I am saying it again. Don't use `Thread.sleep` in a JavaFX Application. It stops the entire UI, and I am pretty sure, that's not what you want.

Comment: @ChandlerBing then what should I use instead. I understand that is what is happening but I am posting this because I need another solution

Comment: @ChandlerBing "Don't use `Thread.sleep` in a JavaFX Application" is not really correct: you should not use `Thread.sleep()` (or any other blocking call) *on the JavaFX Application Thread*. It is fine to do so on a background thread, which is what the OP is attempting to do here (but is calling `run()` instead of `start()` on the thread).

Answer (score 1):

Your timeline only executes once because it only has a single `KeyFrame`, and you have the cycle count set to `1` (so the entire timeline executes once).

You could set the cycle count to `INDEFINITE` (so it repeats forever) and explicitly stop the timeline when your condition is met:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), event -> {

    if(dealer.getScore() >= 17 && (dealer.getScore() >= player.getScore() || dealer.getScore() > 21)) {
        timeline.stop();
    } else {
        newCard(dealer, mainDeck.deal(), false);
        System.out.println("Running Here!");
        LBLDeck.setText(String.valueOf(mainDeck.getRemaingCards()) + " cards remaining");
    }
});

timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

Your thread solution has a couple of problems. First, you are not running the thread's runnable on a background thread at all: `Thread.run()` simply executes the runnable on the current thread, which is the FX Application Thread. So your `Thread.sleep()` blocks the FX Application Thread, causing the UI not to be rendered and to become unresponsive. To actually start the new thread, you should call `Thread.start()` instead.

The second problem is that the `newCard()` and `setText()` methods you call change the UI, which you cannot do from a background thread. You need to do these on the FX Application Thread: you can do this by wrapping them in `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Finally, you are creating a new thread for each card you deal, and (once fixed), launching that thread. So each card will be dealt essentially at the same time, one by each thread. This isn't what you want: you want a background thread to deal one card at a time and pause between each card. So create a single background thread and run the entire loop in it:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    while (dealer.getScore() < 17 || (dealer.getScore() < player.getScore() && dealer.getScore() <= 21)) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            newCard(dealer, mainDeck.deal(), false);
            LBLDeck.setText(String.valueOf(mainDeck.getRemaingCards()) + " cards remaining");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I was able to get the timeline working using your provided example but the problem is the remainder of my code does not wait for the animation to finish. I need the program to wait until the animation is finished to continue. Any thoughts on how to do this?